# playwright is timing out before running page.pause()

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

everything was running fine the code opened a website and carried out some functions

i took a 60 min break and now playwright refuses to do even the most basic function

it loads the website and times out i wrote a new code  to test what was wrong and even that failed

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time
with sync_playwright() as p:
    brower = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
    page = brower.new_page()
    page.goto('https://www.zameen.com/')
    page.pause()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\playwrightzameen.py", line 6, in <module>
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\pyton\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 419, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\pyton\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 79, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "https://www.zameen.com/", waiting until "load"
============================================================
```

i tried to uninstall and reinstall playwright

Comment: Often this happens when the site is blocking your bot. You might try waiting until domcontentloaded to speed it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because your webpage did not load totally, you can set a timeout like:

```
page.goto('https://www.zameen.com/', timeout=100000)
```

Or you can even don't wait till your page is loaded and just navigate without waiting the page to be fully loaded with `timeout=0`

```
page.goto('https://www.zameen.com/', timeout=0)
```